# My rails application doesn't start in my server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My application was working fine, but now is not working well. Neither the application shows me an error
 [image]

Comment: Have you tried ending the process before restarting?

Comment: yes, I have restarted the server. The application is still failing.

Comment: In the above image, does is time-out? or do you have to crtl-z to get the command line?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your environment (system)?